# Make a plot with the points that optim produce while using BFGS for maxit times

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I would like to make a plot with the points that optim produce while using BFGS for maxit times. Is there anyone to help me?
Speciffically, for function f1:

```
i <- 0  
vals <- list()
f1 <- function(x) {
  i <<- i+1
  vals[[i]] <<- x
  x1 <- x[1]
  x2 <- x[2]
  x1^2 + 3*x2^2
  }
```

I would line to plot the points produced from the following `optim (optim(...)$par)` and the intermediate (in `optim`) points using BFGS method (without points utilizing for line search method in BFGS)

```
res <-    optim(c(1.0,1.0), f1, method="BFGS", 
control=list(maxit=1, reltol=0.00001, trace=1, REPORT=1))
```

Comment: This is too broad / vague a request. You should articulate a specific objective, and show what you've attempted so far, including your code and reproducible example and the issue you are encountering

Comment: Still makes no sense. Stops after 2 iterations. Are you hoping to plot the values reported to the screen when `maxit` is larger?

Comment: Yes. I would like to plot the values reported to the screen if maxit not given.